# Centering Text in IPython notebook markdown/heading cells?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to customize my notebook, make it more readable and stylish. So for that, I want to start with centering my headers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can actually use the markdown mode for the cell and use the normal HTML code, as in

```
<h1><center>Centered text!</center></h1>
```

Answer (score 21):

Not directly with markdown i think, but you can just enter HTML in the markdown cells:

```
<h3 align="center">This is a centered header</h3>
```

Answer (score 15):

Knowing that in jupyter (ipython) notebook markdown cells the title level is identified by the number of `#` (`#` for top level headings or h1, `##` for h2, ....), I use the following combination of HTML and markdown:

`# <center>Your centered level h1 title</center>`

`## <center>Your centered level h2 title</center>`

etc..

It's straightforward and the easiest to remember but please do comment if there's any disadvantage in doing so.

Tested in jupyter version 4.4.0 (not sure about other version but no reason it doesn't work).

Answer (score 8):

the easy way for me is just :

`# <center> some fancy title here`

**it works without closing the tag**, so i usually copy "<center>" and past it away in a single step when i finish.

Comment: In VSCode, you have to have a space after the hash:  # <center> title goes here

Comment: corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following lines - text cell.

```
<center>Your centered level h1 title</center>

<center> some fance title here
```

from [Markdown_Guideline](https://github.com/mattcone/markdown-guide)

Answer (score -3):

It's quite simple to make your text stylish in Jupyter-notebook as it's syntax are similar to HTML.

For example, you can use the following commands to play with your texts:

1.`**bold_text**` will make your test bold like **bold_text**.
2.`*italic_text*`  will result in italic text like *italic_text*
3.`***bold_italic_text***` will result in bold and italic text like ***bold_italic_text*** 
4. You can use `<h1> header1 </h1>` to make the text as header like

## header1

You can replace h1 within the angular brackets with any number h2,h3 etc. to get header of different sizes.
5. For text alignment you can use  Centered_text  to align you text to the center.
6. Use `<br>` to breakline or if you want the following text to be printed in next line.

These are just basic things, you can do many more things.

Answer (score -3):

if you want to make a header you can easily use # at the beginning of text to make it big size and also bold, ## will also do the same but text size will be smaller, you can reduce the size of the bold text by increasing the #s up to 6.

Comment: Providing an example of what you are suggesting (code itself, screenshot of the code) would make this comment more helpful.