# Centering Headings in IPython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to center heading cells in IPython notebook.

I know it is possible to create centered headlines by writing HTML, but then I can't get a reference to the cell when using table of contents (nbtoc ext.)

Is there a way to write HTML headings with reference or heading cells with centered text?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering Text in IPython notebook markdown/heading cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575012/centering-text-in-ipython-notebook-markdown-heading-cells)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to center a heading without custom css, you can surround your text with center tags.
For example, if you wanted to make a centered h1 title cell:

```
# <center>Title</center>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use:

```
<h3 align="center">This is a centered header</h3>
```

as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576298/2063031).

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using a custom css; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850829/new-ipython-notebook-templating) for more details on setting up the profile and the appropriate files.

An example custom css can be found in Barba's [12 Steps to Navier Stokes course](https://github.com/barbagroup/CFDPython) although the [actual file](https://github.com/barbagroup/CFDPython/blob/master/styles/custom.css) may contain more detail than you need. The actual [ipython notebooks](https://github.com/barbagroup/CFDPython/tree/master/lessons) there directly load the css, rather than using a profile method, which also works. To center the headings, just modify the css file to

```
h1 {
    ...
    text-align: center;
}
```

as usual.